# Ripple effect which shows content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a small bubble that, when clicked, expands to fill the entire screen and shows some content in it.

This is my test with transform: http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/ofDFr
This is the one with width and height: http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/rlDpI

The problem is that I'm having problems displaying the inner content of the bubble...

I've tried with `transform: scale(x)` and changing the width and height but both the solutions have problems (aka, nothing is displayed correctly).

Mockup:

[image: Imgur]

Do you have any suggestion?

### Edit:

This is another attempt, it is almost what I need but it has weird beavhiors when you resize the page and has some smooth transition of the position of the inner content when expanded which should not be there.

http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/jqswi

Answer (score 1):

Here's one which transitions the width and height:

It also uses the css only checkbox hack for the click event.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/3pjf9puk/3/)**

### Markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb" />
<label for="cb"></label>
```

### CSS

```
label {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
label:before {
    content:'';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1800/1800/food) center center no-repeat blue;
    position: absolute;
}
input {
    display:none;
}
input:checked + label {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the content should not move inside the bubble, and the bubble should be a circle during the entire transition.

Comment: @FezVrasta  -I updated my answer - take another look!

Comment: now when the bubble is expanded it does not fill the entire page...  it's not like my example.

Comment: that's because you wanted it to be a circle.

Comment: I want it to be a circle which expands to fill the entire page, look at the gif to see the wanted effect

Answer (score 0):

How does [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lpiCJ) look.

Basically I put inner outside so it wont get resized as well, and set it with the same position as the ripple. I also `display: none;` at first so the text is not shown, and then on ripple `click()` (when its expanded) I have `$(".inner").show();`

```
<div class="ripple">

</div>
<div class="inner">
  <p>Something very cool! It should not reflow during the transition actually.</p>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

**[New link here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nxqIu)**

Basically Instead of changing scale am changing the width and height instead.

```
.ripple.expanded {
  border-radius: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  width:100%;
  height: 500px;
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

Comment: It should be shown while the ripple is expanding, like the ripple is an hole which shows content behind it...

Comment: I am sorry, I don't get what you mean can you elaborate?

Comment: I'll add a mockup in few mins. Sorry

Comment: ah, I see. Let me check

Comment: I think I got it, but there are a few changes in the functionality, posting in a few secs

Comment: It reflows and is not rounded :(